# How to set a delegate to the owning view in Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, delegates

I've got a `parentViewController` with a navigation controller.

I push a view on the navigation controller. Now I can easily set its delegate to self (to make it point to my `parentViewController`), however from the child view I will push the next and the next view onto the navigationcontroller. Now I want the last view also to have its delegate point to the parent view.

e.g.

```
parentWindowController (navigationController)
```

- firstViewController --> secondViewController --> thirdViewController

Is it possible to set the delegate of the **thirdViewController** to the **parentWindowController** from within its initialization?

The third view is created in the second view therefore I couldn't set this in the beginning.

I wonder how I can reference the parentWindow.

It might be the wrong approach, please let me know if it can be done easier/better?

Comment: Shouldn't all your views be controlled by the viewController?

Comment: You mean by the ParentViewController? No I think not, I only want to send a few messages from some subViews to the parent window view controller (which only has the navigationcontroller and some logic that is useful for all these views).

Comment: There should be a parentView method (or something analogous)

Comment: @Daniel self.delegate = self.parentViewController; (in the init of the thirdViewController gives me a warning: assigning to 'id<ThirdViewControllerDelegate>' from incompatible type 'UIViewController *'.

Comment: @Roderik that's just because it isn't obvious to the compiler that the `parentViewController` implements the `ThirdViewControllerDelegate` protocol, which isn't surprising because it would need to be able to figure out the set of every single potential parent view controller for that controller, which is non trivial. If you know it's okay then add an explicit cast to get rid of the warning.

Comment: @Tommy If I do cast it like `self.delegate = (id <ProjectPickerViewControllerDelegate>) self.parentViewController;` it will not complain but nothing does happen when calling `[self.delegate showStatisticsForProject:currentEntry];` which is a method of the protocol that is implemented in the parent controller (it won't be called). The same idea does work however for the first view controller where I set the delegate to self from within the parent view controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by assigning the delegate for firstViewController within the parentViewController.

Now when I create the second view controller I pass this delegate on. When I create the third view controller I can set the delegate to the initially passed through delegate. This works.

I am still curious however if it was possible to do this directly from within the ThirdViewController without passing it through.

Comment: Couldn't you just do `[[[thirdViewController parentViewController] parentViewController] delegate]`? I'm not an IOS programmer, but that seems like it should work